# If a background: url(image.gif) is set globally for all H1, H2, H3 and .text .text-arrow how do I turn it off for one or two elements?

Tags: html, css

I am having a little issue with a page that is displaying an image for all H1, H2 texts. It is set globally like this?

```
.text h1,
.text h2,
.text .title-arrow {
    color:#a6a6a6;
    font-family:'MelbourneRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:23px;
    background:url(images/arrow_1_green.png) 0 3px no-repeat;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    margin:10px 0 20px 0;
    line-height: 23px;
}
```

However I would like to turn off this arrow image feature for just one or two occasions? It's a really newbie question so I'm sorry if it offends anyone?

Comment: You'd want to set the background image to none either by creating a new class and applying that to the elements in question, or a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will apply to all `h1` with class `text`, `h2` with class `text` or elements with both `text` and `title-arrow` as classes.

If you want to disable it on only one or two elements that have one of the above, then you need to assign it a new class, for example, `no-arrow`

the css would then be:

```
.no-arrow {
    background:none !important;
}
```

note, the `!important` is used to **force** an override of the background property (should work in almost all cases).

Comment: Thanks I used, .no-arrow {
    background:none !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Simpy you can do so by rewite you new defention for that component  directly under the previous definition

// this is your old css

```
.title-arrow , h3 , h5 h6, div {
background:url(images/OLD.png) 0 3px no-repeat ! important;
```

}

// write this under the previous

```
.title-arrow {
background:url(images/RED.png) 0 3px no-repeat ! important;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, I used class="no-arrow" .no-arrow {
    background:none !important;
}

Comment: well .thats great .plese mark my answer as helpful :)

Comment: That was helpful, but my status only allows me to mark one answer as correct.